# Send browser to file instead of directory (with same name) with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, directory

I have a page like:

https://example.com/catalog.php (which offers catalogs for download)

And I have a directory like:

https://example.com/catalog/ (which contains the catalogs of course)

Now I want to do a RewriteRule like this:

RewriteRule ^catalog/(.*?)/?$ catalog.php?var=x

What would be the RewriteCond to send the browser to the page instead of the directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was quite simple: If the filename is a directory, rewrite to php file:

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^catalog/?$ catalog.php?var=foo

Hope I won't find out that I'm somehow mistaken.